# ui-grid How to disable client side filter?

Tags: angular, angular-ui, ui-grid

I do server side filter, user type in top of a column, I generate filter string and load filtered data from server side. But I don't want the typed in filter to be in effect on client side too, it will filter out unexpectedly.

For example, a column is for voucher id, user could type in comma separated string like '12,22,33' to search for three voucher records, but the client side filter with it will hide all the three records returned.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

After digging around I've seen that you can configure this on older versions:

```
        filterOptions: {  // no more in v3.0.+
            filterText: "",
            useExternalFilter: false
        },
```

Taken from: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options

However, this looks like the correct grid options to use on v3.0.+:

```
        options = {
            // ...
            useExternalFiltering: true,
            // ...
        };
```